An optimal proof of the theorem in Coq
On the link Basics I encountered the following problem: Prove the following theorem, which states that as long as the grade starts above F-, the lower_grade option indeed lowers the grade. As usual, destructing everything at once is not a good idea. A careful use of destruct combined with rewriting is a better approach.
Hint: If you defined your grade_comparison function as suggested, you will need to rewrite using letter_comparison_Eq in two cases. The remaining case is the only one in which you need to destruct a letter. The case for F will probably benefit from lower_grade_F_Minus.
Theorem letter_comparison_Eq :
  forall l, letter_comparison l l = Eq.
Proof.
  intros [].
  - reflexivity.
  ...
Qed.

Definition grade_comparison (g1 g2 : grade) : comparison := 
   match g1, g2 with
   | Grade l1 m1, Grade l2 m2 => 
      match (letter_comparison l1 l2) with
      | Eq => modifier_comparison m1 m2
      | Lt => Lt
      | Gt => Gt
      end 
   end.

Lemma grade_comparison_Eq :
  forall l m1 m2,
    grade_comparison (Grade l m1) (Grade l m2) = modifier_comparison m1 m2.
Proof.
  intros l m1 m2.
  unfold grade_comparison.
  rewrite letter_comparison_Eq.
  reflexivity.
Qed.

Theorem lower_grade_F_Minus : lower_grade (Grade F Minus) = (Grade F Minus).
Proof.
  simpl. reflexivity.
Qed.

After many attempts, I arrived at the following result. However, it seems to me that the proof of the theorem is far from optimal.
Theorem lower_grade_lowers :
  forall (g : grade),
    grade_comparison (Grade F Minus) g = Lt -> grade_comparison (lower_grade g) g = Lt.
Proof.
  intros g H.
  destruct g as [l m].
  unfold grade_comparison in *.
  destruct l.
    + rewrite letter_comparison_Eq in H.
      destruct m. 
      - simpl. reflexivity.
      - simpl. reflexivity.
      - rewrite lower_grade_F_Minus. rewrite letter_comparison_Eq. rewrite <- H. reflexivity.
    + destruct m.
      - simpl. reflexivity.
      - simpl. reflexivity. 
      - simpl. reflexivity. 
    + destruct m.
      - simpl. reflexivity.
      - simpl. reflexivity. 
      - simpl. reflexivity. 
    + destruct m.
      - simpl. reflexivity.
      - simpl. reflexivity. 
      - simpl. reflexivity. 
    + destruct m.
      - simpl. reflexivity.
      - simpl. reflexivity. 
      - simpl. reflexivity.       
Qed.

I can use only rewriting, simplification and destruction strategies. Also believe that within the concepts allowed, there is a better way to prove the theorem. However, I am out of ideas on what to do next.

There might be a better way to go at the proof all together but you already can simplify the proof by chaining tactics. For instance, repetition like
destruct m.
- simpl. reflexivity.
- simpl. reflexivity. 
- simpl. reflexivity. 

can simply be written as
destruct m; simpl; reflexivity.

You could then discard most subgoals by using goal selectors, writing:
destruct l.
2-5: destruct m; simpl; reflexivity

On the Coq Plaform Docs website, there is a tutorial about chaining tactics to factorize and simplify your code. You can check it out for more information on interactive intro to the subject.
